# Missing Template error if f.collection option is not selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my form, if a user leaves a required field blank and tries to create the post, the correct message pops up that they need to fill in that required field first.

But if the user doesn't select an option from the drop down f.collection_select menu and tries to submit the form, it doesn't let the user know that they need to choose an option but insteadi get a missing template error.

There is no error however if all the fields are filled in and post goes to the show page as intended, so i'm confused why it's bringing up a missing template error if any of the required f.collection options are not selected.

```
    div class="panel-body">

        <%= simple_form_for(@job, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
        <%=f.collection_select :category_id,Category.all, :id ,:name, {:prompt=> "Select Category" ,:required=> true} %>
        <%=f.collection_select :city_id, City.all, :id ,:name,:prompt=> "Select City" %>


        <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <br>
        <%= f.input :title,required: true,label: "Your Business Name (required)" %>
        <%= f.input :description,required: true,label: "Tell Us About Your Service (required)" %>
        </div>

    <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn btn-primary") do %>
    <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i> List Service</span>
        <% end %>
```

Missing Template error message

```
 Missing template jobs/New, application/New with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what the action does in your controller, may you are redirecting you user for a path with no have template, this error is the correct.

Otherwise you can check if your form is sending the correct HTTP method, look eht example:

The path:

```
POST http://url.com/resources
```

Will send you user to #create method (usually)

The same path
    GET http://url.com/resouces
Will send you user to a #index, needs a template to render

OBS: I'am new in the platform, can't comment yet, try to leave a description of your error.

UPDATE

The error (Missing Template) is because yout controller is trying to render new and you don't have a jobs.new.html.erb file.

For solve the required change your collection to this:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:city_id, City.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Choose a city'}, {:required => true}) %>
```

Comment: The post submits fine when the user has filled all the required fields and it redirects to the show page of the post after submitting, the problem is if the user doesn't select an option from the required f.collection_select drop down menu it gives the missing template error.

Comment: The error (Missing Template) is because yout controller is trying to render `new` and you don't have a `jobs.new.html.erb` file.

Comment: For solve the required change your collection to this:
<%= f.collection_select(:city_id, City.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Choose a city'}, {:required => true}) %>

Comment: nice, sorry by me english